# How to stream video from camera using QT6 and GStreamer

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, rtmp, qt6

Currently I am trying to develop videochat application that stream video from camera over rtmp.
So, I need something like

```
mediaRecorder->setOutput(QUrl("gst-pipeline: appsrc ... rtmpsink"))
```

But this solution does not work in Qt6, because gstreamer custom pipelines support was removed.

So, how to make QMediaRecorder write data to gstreamer pipeline?